# Return ArrayCollection from SELECT query

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

In my AIR app i am trying to get the names from sqlite database as an ArrayCollection . Here is my code.

```
 private function visitorName():void {

 var sqlText:String = "SELECT name FROM user";
 visitorNames = new SQLStatement;
 visitorNames.sqlConnection = dbConn;
 visitorNames.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, visitornamesResult);
 visitorNames.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
 visitorNames.text = sqlText;
 visitorNames.execute();

}

 private function visitornamesResult(event:SQLEvent):Array {
  var result:SQLResult = visitorNames.getResult();
  var  namesList:Array = new Array();
  namesList = result.data;
  datafield3.dataProvider = namesList;
  return namesList;
 }
```

What should i do  to get the results to an ArrayCollection by calling the visitorName() function? 
Is it possible to get return value from a nested function?I know the visitorName function should be changed to ArrayCollection type and should declare an ArrayCollection variable inside it .. but not so sure how to proceed .. any help appreciated ..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, notice that `visitornamesResult` is an event handler, so you won't be able to get the return value of that function.

You will want to actually put the result somewhere when you get it (in the UI? or in a model?)

Let's keep it simple, and just assign it to your `datafield3.dataProvider`:

```
private function visitorName(): { ... /* same as before */ }

private function visitornamesResult(event:SQLEvent):void {
    var result:SQLResult = visitorNames.getResult();

    // this is how you create an ArrayCollection with a provided Array
    var visitors: ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( result.data ); 

    datafield3.dataProvider = visitors;
}
```

Comment: Hi Cristi...... i do get the names in my datagrid (datafield3) already .. but just needed those as ArrayCollection to populate an autocomplete text field .. that was what i was trying .. anyway thanks for your time

Comment: There you have it, the `visitors` is an ArrayCollection that wraps your result array. 

The important thing is: to convert an Array to ArrayCollection: `new ArrayCollection( array );`. An ArrayCollection just wraps an Array to provide the IList and ICollectionView functionality. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html

Comment: @ Cristi I invoked [Bindable] private var visitors:ArrayCollection  outside the function and asigned visitors = new ArrayCollection(result.data) inside function .. but it  is returning [object.Object] ... trying again :)

Comment: This could be because your component needs a labelField/labelFunction to know what to display.